# Django HttpResponse in JsonResponse

Tags: python, django, serialization, httpresponse, jsonresponse

In my django project in order to avoid another request I would like to return a JsonResponse with a HttpResponse in there like this:

`JsonResponse({"known": True, "space": render(request, 'space.html')}, status=200)`

Django process returns the normal internal error `Object of type HttpResponse is not JSON serializable`

I tried all the web solutions (serializer, etc.) and can not find a way to return a json format (necessary for my javascript) with dictionary entries with one of them being an entire html page that I can use with then with `$("body").html(response["space"])`.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

The `render` function returns a `HttpResponse`, and indeed, the `json` serializer does not know how to handle this.

You can instead use [**`render_to_string`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) to render it to a string instead:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

…

JsonResponse({
    'known': True,
    'space': render_to_string('space.html', request=request)
})
```